# Can I search for one value in an array, then return the neighbours of the cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table of data of this form, but much larger:

```
12 11 09 07 06 04 03 02 01 00 02

10 09 08 06 06 03 02 01 00 01 02

10 09 07 05 04 03 02 01 00 01 03

09 08 06 04 03 02 01 00 01 02 04

07 06 05 03 02 01 00 01 03 05 07
```

All the horizontal rows start large then decrease cell by cell until they reach a minimum, then increase again.

I currently search each row to find this minimum, then return the header of that column.
What I would also like to do is, within each row, search for the minimum value and then return the smallest of the 2 neighbours (to the left and right).
e.g. for row 1, search the row for the minimum value --> `00`, then check the two neighbours, 01, and 02, and return the smaller of them, `01`.

Thanks

Using Lookups I've struggled because my search field is the same as the field I want to return values from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theory you display should assert that the n+1 smallest value is ***always*** next to the smallest value. Therefor it's not needed to look to the left/right at all. Try the below:

[image]

Formula in `M2`:

```
=HSTACK(BYROW(A2:K6,LAMBDA(a,XLOOKUP(MIN(a),a,A1:K1))),BYROW(A2:K6,LAMBDA(a,SMALL(a,2))))
```

---

If it's only the 2nd smallest number per row you want then use:

```
=BYROW(A2:K6,LAMBDA(a,SMALL(a,2)))
```

Comment: That insight as to just needing the second smallest number in the row was very useful, but given that, the "SMALL" function you use at the end gives exactly that. Not sure exactly what the rest of the formula is doing? I'm not all that familiar with LAMBDA functions. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if you are asking me something now @BrassMonkey.

Comment: Well your answer has let me do what I needed, so thanks a lot there! I guess I'm just confused given that the formula SMALL(array,2) basically did exactly what I needed, so what is the rest of the formula you pasted adding? Should I take the time to understand it for future use? @JvdV

Comment: No in that case just take `=SMALL(array,2)`. I read your question as though you both want to return the header of the smallest number **and** you also want to return the 2nd smallest number. So therefor it got more lengthy @BrassMonkey.